# Exporting (only) final iteration from ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm using an iterator in ModelBuilder (1) to merge files, using a feedback loop (2). The output file is named "Output_%n%.txt", (3), so each file is unique.

Now, I'm merging a fair number of files, so I'm trying to speed the process up. Since I don't care about the interim files, I can write them out to in_memory. But I would like to save the final file, viz: "Output_167.txt" to C:\myfile rather than in_memory.

(0) Yes, APPEND would work, but this has other applications.

(1) http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000001n000000.htm

(2) http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Iteration_using_feedback

(3) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005s000000

Comment: How about you write them all to in_memory as you are then the next step is to write out the final dataset,  you know what %n% is so it should be fairly easy to export out. I am surprised that the in_memory workspace allows that naming convention.

Comment: @horbbydd. That does work, but I'm trying to generalize the tool in such a way that I can apply it to multiple tables of unknown length. I could use a count function or table properties to get the number of rows, and then export when x=%n%, but doing so would require using a nested model, so it didn't redo the count multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> How about you write them all to in_memory as you are then the next
>   step is to write out the final dataset, you know what %n% is so it
>   should be fairly easy to export out.  Hornbydd Oct 24 at 7:51

@Hornbydd Months later, I finally understand your reply. I could not think how to get n, realized that for this specific purpose, I'm using a FOR loop, with a model parameter. It will take some text slicing, but I can extract the n from %n%. For cases where I am not, such as iterating over rows in a data-set, I can use max(ID) to get the iteration count.